# Read values from a videofeed

Tags: python, video-processing

I am new to programming and I want to create a program that is able to read certain values from a video feed. The values I am looking for is the colour of a 3 numbers that will change over time. Any tips are welcome. Thank you in advance :)

I have not tried anything yet since I have no idea on how to read a feed, this is the first place I have asked. I will continue to google :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

While I would suggest doing a lot more research, to start you can use [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html) to capture the video feed. Code like this should be able to capture the live video from the webcam, or you can connect an IP address too:

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # 0 for webcam, you can put an IP here or other things too.
cv2.namedWindow("Camera Feed", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.setWindowProperty("Camera Feed", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if frame is None:
        continue
    cv2.imshow("Camera Feed", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

You can then use TesseractOCR through PyTesseract to process and find the characters in the video feed. [The docs are here.](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/)